# Programmatic creation of Post in a Page not visible from other facebook accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using a facebook account(account1) - I create a page(page1). Now I use facebook client SDK for C# to post posts(and links) programatically to this newly created page(page1).

Now i log off and login using another facebook account(account2). Now i subscribe to the page(*page1) i created using account1. But I am not able to see any post from this account.

now I am doing another try, this time I am posting to post1 through account1 manually and Now i can see this post from account2.

What am I missing.

Comment: You need to set your app public in the app dashboard; before you do that, all content created through it will only be visible to people with a role (admin/developer/tester) in the app.

Comment: superb . excellent. That solved me a great problem where I was struggling for hours and hours. Please answer this separately and I will mark that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your app “public” in the app dashboard.

Before you do that, all content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app (admin/developer/tester.)